# File and method navigation in vim

Tags: vim

I've worked mostly in NetBeans and had to switch to vim for this one project and was wondering if there is an easy way to get file and method navigation working on vim. On Netbeans (and probably every decent IDE) you can have pane open which lists all the files associated with the current project and all the methods in the current file so that you can jump around in your code quickly instead of having to waste time scrolling through it. I was wondering if there is a way to add this feature to vim, it would make my life so much easier.

Comment: File nav is pretty easy with NERD tree.  But what I really want and have been looking for is quick method nav.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use NerdTree (mentioned by George) for filesystem navigation and [taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) for methods/classes navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out NERD tree for the file system navigation:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658

Not sure about the method piece.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways of navigating through files and inside a file with vim that your best move should be to take a look at its [documentation](http://www.vim.org/docs.php).

Be prepared to a hard learning curve. Be prepared to love vim after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward and backward search to find whatever method you need, at least that's what I do in both Emacs and ViM.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, NERD Tree is excellent.

Also, if you like the Netbeans behavior of preserving tabs and open files, see:

- :help sessions
- :help mksession
- :help source

For other Netbeans-like features, try:

- :help tabs
- :help mark

Regarding method navigation, I highly recommend learning about vim folding. You may like it better than Netbean's method navigation. Start with :help folding. Beyond that, Google around. It's a deep subject, but well worth investigating.

Alternately, you can use / and ? to jump to methods by name (by searching forward and backward, respectively) and combine that with marks--see :help mark--to make jumping to named bookmarks on specific methods more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

NERDTree is great, as many have already said.  You might want to check out CTAGS, which allows you to place your cursor over a method name and press a key combination to jump to the definition of that method, even if it's in another flle.

Answer (score 0):

Try Project plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69

Comment: That looks old (2006-10-13?). Is it any good by way of recent Vim functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I use ctags and tried setting the properties like set sm
set ai
syntax on
let java_highlight_all=1
let java_highlight_functions="style"
let java_allow_cpp_keywords=1 in vimrc file as mentioned in this link 
http://www.builderau.com.au/program/java/soa/Configure-vi-for-Java-application-development/0,339024620,320276164,00.htm

It is always good to bring ur IDE to vim which makes life easier with fewer key strokes